# PNGs with transparent backgrounds are uploading to database with a black background

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
// include resize class plugin script
include('lib/inc/resize-class.php');

// if conditional check if upload form has been submitted
if($_POST['imgsubmit']=='UPLOAD') {

    // set directory name based on property id
    $dirname = $_GET['p'];

    // set image type id to standard image type id
    //$imageType = '0';

    // set added by based on session user ID
    //$addedBy = $_SESSION['roleid'];

    // define the path to the folder which will hold your home images
    //make a properties folder in the imgs directory
    $productsFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pyro-pizza/lib/img/products/';

    // define full path to property ID folder
    $fullpath = $productsFolder.$dirname.'/';
    //echo ($fullpath);
    // if properties folder does not exist, make it then set its permissions to read/write all 777
    //checks to see if a directory file exists
    if(!is_dir($productsFolder)){
        //mkdir making a directory
        mkdir($productsFolder);
        //chmod change permissions to the folder
        chmod($productsFolder, 0777);
    }

    // if no sub directory exists for this property
    if (!file_exists($fullpath)) {
//echo $fullpath;
    mkdir($fullpath);
    }
        // recheck for property directory
        if(file_exists($fullpath)){

            // create array of acceptable file types (pjpeg is for progressive jpeg, jpg/jpeg are the same save for extension length)
            $fileType= array('gif','jpeg','pjpeg','jpg','png');

            // set max file size in MB
            $maxSize=2;

                // if uploaded file's type is in the file type array (after removeing 'image/') && the file size is less then max size multiplied by the number of bytes in a single MB
                if (in_array(str_replace("image/","",$_FILES['photo']['type']),$fileType) && $_FILES['photo']['size'] < ($maxSize*1000000)){

                    // check if a file with the same name of the uploaded file exists in the property ID directory
                    if (file_exists($fullpath . $_FILES["photo"]["name"])) {
                    $upload_msg .= "<p class=\"alert\">". $_FILES["photo"]["name"] . " already exists.</p>";
                    } else {
                    // move uploaded file from temporary storage to specified directory
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], ($fullpath . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]));

                    //=================================================================================== Create Thumbnail
                    // *** 1) Initialise / load image
                    $resizeObj = new resize($fullpath . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
                    if(!resizeObj) { $upload_msg .= "<p class=\"alert\">Didn't create Thumbnail object</p>"; }
                    // *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
                    $resizeObj -> resizeImage(180, 180, 'crop',0);
                    if(!resizeObj) { $upload_msg .= "<p class=\"alert\">Didn't resize Thumbnail</p>"; }
                    // *** 3) Save image
                    $resizeObj -> saveImage($fullpath . '180_'.$_FILES["photo"]["name"], 100);
                    //=================================================================================== Create full size
                    // *** 1) Initialise / load image
                    $resizeObj = new resize($fullpath . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
                    if(!resizeObj) { $upload_msg .= "<p class=\"alert\">Didn't create Full Size object</p>"; }
                    // *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
                    $resizeObj -> resizeImage(700, 700, 'crop',0);
                    if(!resizeObj) { $upload_msg .= "<p class=\"alert\">Didn't resize Full Size</p>"; }
                    // *** 3) Save image
                    $resizeObj -> saveImage($fullpath . '700_'.$_FILES["photo"]["name"], 100);
                    //=================================================================================== Create Primary size
                    // *** 1) Initialise / load image
                    $resizeObj = new resize($fullpath . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
                    if(!resizeObj) { $upload_msg .= "<p class=\"alert\">Didn't create Primary Size object</p>"; }
                    // *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
                    $resizeObj -> resizeImage(450, 450, 'landscape',0);
                    if(!resizeObj) { $upload_msg .= "<p class=\"alert\">Didn't resize Primary Size</p>"; }
                    // *** 3) Save image
                    $resizeObj -> saveImage($fullpath . '450_'.$_FILES["photo"]["name"], 100);

                    // insert image data into database
                    $sql= "INSERT INTO `images`(`imageid`, `productid`, `caption` , `active`, `filename`, `addeddate`)
                    VALUES (NULL,'".$dirname."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['caption'])."',1,'".$_FILES["photo"]["name"]."',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
                    //echo ($sql);
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                    }

                }

        }
}
?>

<h3>Image Upload and Edit Section:</h3>
    <form id="addphotos" class="stylized img-uploader-margin" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="img-uploader-margin">
    <label class="required" for="photo">Photo </label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo"/>
    </div>

        <div>
    <label class="required" for="caption">Caption</label>
    <input type="text" class="text required" id="caption" name="caption" size="24" />
    </div>

    <div class="update-product-btn-container">
    <input type="submit" name="imgsubmit" value="UPLOAD" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <?php
        // SELECT imgs from DB
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `productid` = ".$_GET['p'].";";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        //echo $sql;
        // Display all images
        if($result){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $tmp = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pyro-pizza/lib/img/products/'.$row['productid'].'/180_'.$row['filename'];
                    // if thumbnail image exists echo link to full size of full size
                    if (file_exists($tmp)) {
                    echo '<a rel="expand" href="'.'/pyro-pizza/lib/img/products/'.$row['productid'].'/700_'.$row['filename'].'" target="_blank" class="thumb"><img src="'.'lib/img/products/'.$row['productid'].'/180_'.$row['filename'].'" class="thumb" alt="'.$row['caption'].'"/></a>';
                    if($row['imageid']!=1){
                    echo'<a class="trainer-image-edit" href="edit-images.php?p='.$row['productid'].'&img='.$row['imageid'].'&act=mkp">Make Primary</a>';
                        }
                    echo'<a class="trainer-image-edit" href="edit-images.php?p='.$row['productid'].'&img='.$row['imageid'].'&act=del&filename='.$row['filename'].'">Delete</a>';
                    }
                }
        }
    ?>
```

Using this basic_upload.php I am able to upload images for my products to my database to use in my website. I want to use a PNG for the images for the products, but when I upload the images the PNGs have a black background instead of a transparent one like they had originally, before uploading them.

I am still a novice when it comes to this and wondered if anyone had any ideas on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Instead of inserting `NULL` into an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, remove that column from the list and you can just skip it, the default will be applied automatically.

Comment: Also try saving your images to the filesystem and referencing that path in your database. Check some sort of hash or checksum on your uploaded file versus the one you actually save to be sure they're the same. You may be inadvertently mangling the content.